# need to do arithmetic operations in django templates tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to add three variables in django templates.

```
<p>{{s.a}}+{{s.b}}+{{s.c}}</p>
```

but its not doing the addition. how to do the addition of this tree variables and display final result without using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `add` template filter:

```
<p>{{ s.a|add:s.b|add:s.c }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better if you do your calculations in your views.py then pass them through render or render_to_response

```
def something(request): 
    value = your arithmetic...
    return render(request, "template names", {'value': value})
```